# C# Encontrar la última aparición de un String en un archivo

Tags: c#

Necesito tomar la última aparición de la traza de un log, dada una cadena de caracteres específica en C#, algo como:

```
lines = File.ReadLines(logPath)
        .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("param"))
        .Take(20);
```

Ese código funciona, pero retorna 20 líneas desde la primera aparición de "param" en el log, y lo necesito 20 líneas desde la última vez que aparezca "param".

Comment: Si utilizas .NET Core 2 o superior, puedes utilizar `TakeLast(20);`

Comment: Pero eso me daría las últimas 20 líneas del log?? o las 20 líneas despues de encontrar el texto "param"??

Comment: Utilizalo luego del `.SkipWhile`, en lugar de `.Take`, por tanto actúa en la colección ya filtrada, es decir, te dará las últimas 20 líneas que cumplen con tu condición.

Comment: Ah, lo siento, no había comprendido bien tu pregunta. Vos queres las últimas 20 líneas luego de que aparezca por última vez, por favor ignora mis comentarios, no resuelven tu duda.

Comment: Lo que necesitas son 20 líneas arriba o 20 líneas abajo de la última aparición?

Comment: 20 líneas abajo, luego de que aparezca "param", las siguientes 20 líneas, pero "param" podría aparecer varias veces en el log, necesito las 20 líneas despues de aparezca por última vez, para que me traiga los datos de la última ejecución.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La primera solución que se me viene a la mente es la de usar [Array.FindLastIndex(T[], Predicate)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findlastindex?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Primero obtener el índice de la última línea donde aparece el contenido que buscas, luego utilizas ese dato para, utilizando [Skip(IEnumerable, Int32)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netframework-4.7.2) llegar a los datos que buscas, por ejemplo.

Asumiendo que el txt es el siguiente:

```
para para
param
param
papa
papa
pepe
lala
nana
param
param
la 
param
un registro
dos registros
tres registros
ejemplo
```

Podrías aplicar el concepto planteado arriba de la siguiente manera:

```
//Leo el txt y lo guardo en el array lines    
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
//Búsco el índice de la última aparición de param
int index = Array.FindLastIndex(lines, x => x == "param");
//Si es -1 (param no existe en el array) lanzo una excepción para luego controlarla..
if(index != -1)
{ 
    //Uso skip para saltear las las líneas, y tomo las siguientes 20 líneas
    var result = lines.Skip(index + 1).Take(20);                
}
else
{
    throw new Exception("No existe!");
}
```

En el ejemplo anterior, la salida sería:

```
un registro
dos registros
tres registros
ejemplo
```

---

Otra solución simple (y sin Linq), podría ser usando un bucle `for`, por ejemplo (asumo que en `lines` se encuentra el `txt` para no repetir código):

```
IList<string> result = new List<string>();

for(int i = 0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    //En caso de que coincida la condición, limpio la lista para que empiece de nuevo..
    if (lines[i] == "param")
    {
        result.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        //Si aún no llego a 20, agrego el elemento
        if(result.Count<20)
        result.Add(lines[i]);
    }
}
```

De esta manera, la lista se limpiará siempre que aparezca la palabra `param` la lista se limpiará, hasta que sea la última vez, de modo que obtendremos lo que buscamos!